# How to install Xcode 4 on Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos, operating-system

I can't install Xcode 4. I have some files that I need to open in Xcode 4. However, when I try to install it, it says "Xcode Install Assistant cannot be installed on this disk. The version of OS X is too new." How can I make it think I'm on Lion or Mountain Lion?

Here is a picture:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

Download it in the App Store - it's the newest version and looks like the disc you have doesn't support Mavericks.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am on a Macbook Air. That means no disk for me :(. Also, the App Store only has Xcode 5 now. I got the Xcode 4 install .dmg from the developer website, but I couldn't install it, due to me being on Mavericks.

Comment: Xcode 5 should be able to open anything produced by Xcode 4 (or even earlier versions).

Comment: I have older devices and the support for them by Xcode 5 is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

I feel tired of these preposterous answers. I think that if you want to stick to an older version of something, you should be able to. Also, I don't think software like XCode 4 are that old anyway.

But, to the point: I think XCode **4.6.3** is compatible with Mavericks. I am not sure about previous **4.6.X**, but I think none of them work.

Any versions prior would require a previous operating system. I think you could try using **pacifist** to install the version you want, but I haven't found any guides.

If your problem is with project compatibility, in XCode 5 there is an option to save the project in a way it is compatible with XCode 4.6, and I suppose 4.6 offers a similar option to save in a version prior. Of course, you may need to adapt the code of the projects accordingly. Usually I try to stick with the Snow-Leopard-compatible code, because it compiles fine in all XCode 4.X and 5.X versions.

You can download any of these from the developer website.

I would try partitioning the disk and installing an older Mac OS X. I work with Snow Leopard and Mavericks in the same Mac. I usually do interface tasks in SL and the rest on Mavericks. The other advantage is that I have both XCode 4.2 and 3.2.6 in the same machine, so I can manage some backwards compatibility. =D